# backbone events not firing off html select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am having a problem in backbone where when I select an option from the following html, the event in backbone is not firing. I need to be able to know what city was selected.

```
      <div id="location">
       <label>Select City</label>
          <select id="citySelect">
           <option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option>
           <option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
           <option value="New York">New York</option>
           <option value="Las Vegas">Las Vegas</option>
          </select>
      </div>
```

Backbone code:

```
var cardsView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: 'body',

intialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, 'onselect', 'onclick');
    this.render();
},

render: function(){
    return this;
},

events: {
    'change #citySelect': 'onselect'
},
onclick: function (evt) {
    console.log('click');
    console.log($(evt.currentTarget).val());
    alert($(evt.currentTarget).val());
},
onselect: function (evt) {
    alert(this.$('#citySelect').val());
}
});
var card = new cardsView();
```

Comment: Hmm, it worked for me. I tried it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/f8hYX/1/

Comment: I don't understand why it does not work on my computer. I goto the page in chrome off the file:// protocol and in the console, no log statements show up. weird

Comment: Did you mean error messages? Or the logging your code? If the latter, your code currently only hits `onselect`, so it should only give the alert. You'd need to change the event to your `onclick` one if you want logging.

Comment: yes makes sense, but it doesn't even alert me on select. This is frustrating. It works on jsFiddle but not my browser.

Comment: Yeah doesn't seem like using `file://` would make a difference, especially if you're not getting error messages at all. Maybe try a button and see if a click event works.